# How to handle an error HTTPServer Angular?

Tags: angular

I have got overwritten Http in Angular:

```
return super.request(request, options).map((res: Response) => {

      if (res.json().result.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
        new ErrorWatcher().reportError(res.json().result.errors);
      }

       return res;

     }).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
```

And `catchAuthError` is:

```
private catchAuthError (self: HttpService) {
    return (res: Response) => {

      if (res.status < 400 ||  res.status === 500) {
        console.log('N');
      }

      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }
```

When error appears it returns Observable: `return Observable.throw(res);`.

Therefore my client function falls:

```
this.service.get()
      .subscribe(data => {}, resultError => {
        console.log(resultError);
      });
```

Because it is expects to get `data`.

I need to handle catch only in my HttpService. I dont want to do that like this:

```
this.service.get()
          .subscribe(data => {}, resultError => {
            console.log(resultError);
          }).catch(...);
```

Can I do the following:

Pass here own object ? `return Observable.throw({"errors" : true});` ? And after to make this in client `if (!res.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {}`

I tried this in HttpService:

```
res['errors'] = true;

return Observable.from(res);
```

To throw data otherwise!

Also this way:

```
res.json().push(['errors']);

return Observable.throw(res);
```

Comment: If you dont return the observable.throw() does it still fail? (Just throw it without return statement)

Comment: Can you explain your comment, please

Comment: if you take out the word 'return' just Observable.throw()

Comment: Can I pass here own object ? `return Observable.throw({my object});` ?

Comment: Look my latest edit in question

Comment: You shouldnt have to check for errors in the component that is subscribing. Is the resultError not getting logged in this.service.get()?

Comment: I tried this: `res['errors'] = true;

      return Observable.from(res);`

Comment: does `console.log(resultError);` this line run ever?

Comment: Problem is that instead  ` return Observable.throw(res);` I need return success response with own data.

Comment: catch() only runs when the initial observable throws an error. Inside catch() you should handle the error if you can and then return something to the component. If you end up in the catch() likely you did not receive any data from the http call.

Comment: I need return Observable anyway in catch

Comment: Yes that is correct. If you have something to return to the component then you should return it as Observable.of({data}) if you want to let the component know there was an error you should use Observable.throw("reason for error")

Comment: I tried return data. It gives me error then: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0  for URL: null`

Comment: just use Observable.of(/*whatever you want to send*/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157107/discussion-between-opv-and-rjustin).